# Under what conditions is baking powder kosher

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I'm a Jew from Iran. I want to know if baking powder is kosher without any certificate since they don't exist in Iran. Generally baking powder include TARTARIC ACID.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Hi @Moshiach! I don't know if you are able to access Israeli websites but http://dinonline.org/ is a good place for these kinds of questions. Kol tov!

Answer (score 4):

[Star-K](https://www.star-k.org/), a recognized kosher authority, writes [here](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kosher-lists/3502/no-hechsher-required/) that baking powder is kosher without a hekhsher, if they do not have additives and if food items are not a product of Israel. R Moshe Vaye, a leading kosher food authority in Bnei Brak, [agrees](http://dinonline.org/Bedikat/categories-of-food/).

[Tartaric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartaric_acid) is a natural component of baking powder and not an additive (see e.g., [here](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-6/Baking-Powder.html)). Both [OU Kosher](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/cream-tartar-tartaric-acid-derived-non-kosher-wine-kosher/) and [CRC](http://www.crcweb.org/spice_list.php) write it is kosher without supervision.

Therefore there appears to be no issue with baking powder. Still, since we are not familiar with Iranian manufacturing processes, it would be worth asking other observant Jews if their custom is to use baking powder without certification.